# place tkinter buttons in a row

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

i want to place my buttons in a raw beside each other but when i set row same and change columns they place too far of each other.i tried to remove grid and add `pack()` but again i failed.changing `pady` didn't help me too.what should i do

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("810x490")
root.configure(background='#DCDCDC')
root.title('Hossein Fallah')


def getText():
    output_text.delete("1.0","end")
    result=input_text.get("1.0","end")
    output_text.insert(tk.END,result)
    return result
    
def textClear():
    output_text.delete("1.0","end")
    input_text.delete("1.0","end")

def fileDialog():
 
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select A File", filetype =
    (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")) )

# first text wiget
input_text=tk.Text(root, height=10,width=100,bd=5)
input_text.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 2)

#BTNs
btnRead=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=20, text="ثبت",relief='flat',overrelief='groove',
                    command=getText)
btnRead.grid(row = 2, column = 0,  pady = 2)

btnClear=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=20, text="پاک کردن",relief='flat',overrelief='groove',
                    command=textClear)
btnClear.grid(row = 3, column = 0,  pady = 2)

btnFind =tk.Button(root, height=1, width=20,text = "پیدا کردن فایل",relief='flat',overrelief='groove',
                    command =fileDialog)
btnFind.grid(row = 4, column = 0, pady = 2)

#out text
output_text=tk.Text(root, height=10,width=100,bd=5)
output_text.grid(row = 6, column = 0,  pady = 2)
output_text.insert(tk.END,getText())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: With respect to what are you saying that they are placed far? Using `grid()` properly is your best option.

Comment: cant control distances between each button

Comment: @hossien it still applies. You can just change the column and leave the row the same:
`Button(root, text='Hello world').grid(column=1,row=0)`

Comment: @Arandomcoder it wasn't enough.someone solved it by adding ```columnspan``` to ```text ``` widgets and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `columnspan` option of `grid()`. First start off by removing custom geometry to your window. After that place the widgets all in same row but different column, like:

```
btnRead=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=20, text="ثبت",relief='flat',overrelief='groove', command=getText)
btnRead.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2)

btnClear=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=20, text="پاک کردن",relief='flat',overrelief='groove',command=textClear)
btnClear.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=2)

btnFind =tk.Button(root, height=1, width=20,text = "پیدا کردن فایل",relief='flat',overrelief='groove',command =fileDialog)
btnFind.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=2)
```

Now add the `columnspan` option to both the `Text` widgets, like:

```
input_text=tk.Text(root, height=10,width=100,bd=5)
input_text.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, columnspan=3)

output_text=tk.Text(root, height=10,width=100,bd=5)
output_text.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=2, columnspan=3)
```

What `columnspan=n` does is, it will make room to span `n` columns for the entire width of the single column where the configured widget exists. If you are used to excel, you can imagine this quite easily, like this:

[image: Excel screenshot]